# The type HtmlNode doesn't match the type 'Nullable<'a>'?

Tags: f#

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to parse some Html files. The following code

```
let html = "<div>...</div>"
let doc = new HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)
let node = doc.DocumentNode

let x = node.SelectSingleNode("//div/@xyz") 
        |> Option.ofNullable
```

The last line got the error of

> The type HtmlNode doesn't match the type 'Nullable<'a>'

The following code can convert it

```
let ofNull = function
    | null -> None
    | x -> Some x
```

Is there any built-in construct to do it? I don't want my definition of `ofnull` scatter everywhere in the code/script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in function you are looking for is `Option.ofObj`, not `Option.ofNullable`.

The `Option.ofNullable` converts a value of type `System.Nullable<'a>`, which is a .NET type that is used for turning value types into nullable types. C# has langauge support for this and you can use, for example, `int?` to define type that is similar to `option<int>` in F#.

The `Option.ofObj` function takes any .NET `obj` (actually, a generic type that has a `null` as a value) and returns `Some` if it is not `null` or `None` if it is `null`. The types are:

```
Option.ofNullable : System.Nullable<'a> -> 'a option
Option.ofObj      : 'a -> 'a option
```